# Extracting data from website for Android app

Tags: android, web-scraping, data-extraction

I would like to know regarding the methods of extracting data from a website. I am planning to create an android app where it extracts the data from the website and displays it to the user.

The only problem with the website is the data changes real time. Can someone help me to give me some idea on how to begin with it. Any doubts regarding my question please ask me. I am willing to give more explanations.

Comment: Do you need absolute real time changes to affect the app?

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSoup to parse HTML objects in your Android app. Have a look at this: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

try to use OK HTTP library its good and simple here is the link

http://square.github.io/okhttp/